# Better regex implementation than for looping whole file?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, shell, text

I have files looking like this:

```
#     BJD     K2SC-Flux EAPFlux   Err  Flag Spline
2457217.463564 5848.004 5846.670 6.764 0 0.998291
2457217.483996 6195.018 6193.685 6.781 1 0.998291
2457217.504428 6396.612 6395.278 6.790 0 0.998292
2457217.524861 6220.890 6219.556 6.782 0 0.998292
2457217.545293 5891.856 5890.523 6.766 1 0.998292
2457217.565725 5581.000 5579.667 6.749 1 0.998292
2457217.586158 5230.566 5229.232 6.733 1 0.998292
2457217.606590 4901.128 4899.795 6.718 0 0.998293
2457217.627023 4604.127 4602.793 6.700 0 0.998293
```

I need to **find and count** the lines **with Flag = 1**. (5th column.) This is how I have done it:

```
foundlines=[]
c=0
import re
with open('examplefile') as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f):
        try:
            found = re.findall(r' 1 ', line)[0]
            foundlines.append(index)
            print(line)
            c+=1
        except:
            pass
print(c)
```

In Shell, I would just do `grep " 1 " examplefile | wc -l`, which is much shorter than the Python script above. The python script works, but I am interested in whether **is there a shorter, more compact way to do the task than the script above**? I prefer the shortness of Shell so I would like to have something similar in Python.

Comment: Since the code works, you should consider posting this at [codereview.se]. However, it is clear you do not need a regex to find `1` in between spaces, use `if ' 1 ' in line`.

Comment: Most things in Python can be put on a single line, but that will actively harm readability. Are you sure size is the only thing that matters to you?

Comment: If you like it short, stick to shell.

Comment: Yes, if readability as seriously reduced than I don't mind it being long. Alright, I'll reconsider the shell implementation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shell implementation can be made even shorter, `grep` has `-c` option to get you a count, no need for an anonymous pipe and `wc`:

```
grep -c " 1 " examplefile
```

---

You shell code simply gets you the line counts where the pattern `1` is found, but your Python code additionally keeps a list of indexes of lines where the pattern is matched.

Only to get the line counts, you can use `sum` and genexp/list comprehension, also no need for Regex; simple string `__contains__` check would do as strings are iterable:

```
with open('examplefile') as f:
    count = sum(1 for line in f if ' 1 ' in line)
    print(count)
```

If you want to keep indexes as well, you can stick to your idea with only replacing `re` test with `str` test:

```
count = 0
indexes = []
with open('examplefile') as f:
    for idx, line in enumerate(f):
        if ' 1 ' in line:
            count += 1
            indexes.append(idx)
```

---

Additionally, doing a bare `except` is almost always a bad idea (at least you should use `except Exception` to leave out `SystemExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt` like exceptions), catch only the exceptions you know might be raised.

Also, while parsing structured data, you should use specific tool e.g. here `csv.reader` with space as the separator (`line.split(' ')` should do in this case as well) and checking against index-4 would be safest (see [Tomalak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52149161/3789550)). With the `' 1 ' in line` test, there would be misleading results if any other column contains `1`.

Considering the above, here's the shell way using `awk` to match against the 5-th field:

```
awk '$5 == "1" {count+=1}; END{print count}' examplefile
```

Comment: `... if  ' 1 ' in line` is treacherous.

Comment: @Tomalak I admit it ;) going by the literal example actually.

Comment: Then you should at the very least warn about the risk of false positives.

Answer (score 3):

You have CSV data, you can use the `csv` module:

```
import csv

with open('your file', 'r', newline='', encoding='utf8') as fp:
    rows = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=' ')

    # generator comprehension
    errors = (row for row in rows if row[4] == '1')

for error in errors:
    print(error)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Shortest code

This is a very short version under some specific preconditions:

- You just want to count occurrences like your grep invocation
- There is guaranteed to be only one `" 1 "` per line
- That `" 1 "` can only occur in the desired column
- Your file fits easily into memory

Note that if these preconditions are not met, this may cause issues with memory or return false positives.

```
print(open("examplefile").read().count(" 1 "))
```

## Easy and versatile, slightly longer

Of course, if you're interested in actually doing something with these lines later on, I recommend Pandas:

```
df = pandas.read_table('test.txt', delimiter=" ",
                       comment="#",
                       names=['BJD', 'K2SC-Flux', 'EAPFlux', 'Err', 'Flag', 'Spline'])
```

To get all the rows where Flag is 1:

```
flaggedrows = df[df.Flag == 1]
```

returns:

```
            BJD  K2SC-Flux   EAPFlux    Err  Flag    Spline
1  2.457217e+06   6195.018  6193.685  6.781     1  0.998291
4  2.457218e+06   5891.856  5890.523  6.766     1  0.998292
5  2.457218e+06   5581.000  5579.667  6.749     1  0.998292
6  2.457218e+06   5230.566  5229.232  6.733     1  0.998292
```

To count them:

```
print(len(flaggedrows))
```

returns 4

Comment: Is here the danger of false positives present, as mentioned here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52148942/better-regex-implementation-than-for-looping-whole-file#comment91248561_52149044

Comment: @heemayl I've added caveats and a better answer